# Are there recommended or "best practice" image resolutions for the different media queries of the different devices?

Tags: html, css

Just like the title says: Im wondering if there are some recommended image resolutions for the different media queries of the different devices in 2016, so that on mobile phones e.g. the images load faster because image size is smaller?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

The dimensions<sup>1</sup> of an image are a big factor in the weight<sup>1</sup> of an image, but they are far from the only one. PNGs will be smaller if there are fewer colors. JPGs have their own quirks (which I can't remember). The upshot is that images with the exact same dimensions can vary *widely* in weight.

With this understood, you can see why no established set of sizes will be particularly efficient for every image.

I can think of a couple different routes:

1. Make different images, at increments of weight (e.g. 10KB, 20KB, 40KB, you decide) then make images corresponding to these weights. They *will* have many different dimensions. Use the [`srcset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-srcset) and [`sizes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-sizes) attributes to tell the browser which image to use for any given screen size.
2. Find a list of the most common device sizes ([this site has a few](http://websitedimensions.com/), but you might want to customize it based on your traffic), and make images specifically for each of those. **This method is not future-friendly.** In doing so, you may have to change your "supported resolutions" list every few years [when new devices get popular](http://blog.cloudfour.com/on-the-device-context-continuum/). And, as stated before, some images may not be *worth* creating a custom size for, if the new size will not be much lighter than the original image.

Just to clarify: **The second option is a bad idea.**

For more about responsive images, see:

- [Responsive Images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images), on MDN
- [Responsive Images 101](http://blog.cloudfour.com/responsive-images-101-definitions/), by Jason Grigsby ([Part 9](http://blog.cloudfour.com/responsive-images-101-part-9-image-breakpoints/) is particularly relevant)
- [Responsive Images Breakpoints Generator](http://blog.cloudfour.com/responsive-images-breakpoint-generator/), by Jason Grigsby

Notes:

1. Since "size" is a little vague here, I'm using "dimensions" to refer to width/height of the image and "weight" to refer to the size on disk (bytes, KB, MB, and so forth).

Comment: Browsers don't decide which image is best. The developer does when he writes the srcset/sizes properties. Point 2 is not a good idea since a multitude of devices have a multitude of ranges for their screen size.

Comment: @Rob Yes. I'll rewrite that to make it clearer. And as for Point 2, I concur: it is a very bad idea.

Comment: thanks. so it should make sense to speak from the weight of a whole package of images loaded for each screen size instead of focusing on each one? if yes, there could also be a maximum weight of every package for wach screen size?